# Add Enum to a existing sql column

Tags: mysql, sql, liquibase

There is an existing query to create a column with enums as shown below.

```
ALTER TABLE org ADD COLUMN `classify` ENUM('Arg', 'Agent') NOT NULL;
```

Now, I cannot modify that. I need send another query to add another value, when I try

```
ALTER TABLE org change `classify` ENUM('Arg', 'Agent','brand') NOT NULL;
```

it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
ALTER TABLE org ADD COLUMN classify_aux ENUM('Arg', 'Agent','brand') NOT NULL;

UPDATE org SET classify_aux = classify;

ALTER TABLE org DROP COLUMN classify;

ALTER TABLE org ADD COLUMN `classify` ENUM('Arg', 'Agent','brand') NOT NULL;

UPDATE org SET classify = classify_aux;

ALTER TABLE org DROP COLUMN classify_aux;
```